# how do I get libnice to stop candidate checking

Tags: webrtc, stun, libnice

I am using libnice on a C++ native server which is trying to make a WebRTC peer connection to a web browser client app. Using libnice, the candidate gathering is successful and the Offer/Answer exchange is successful. It then proceeds with the checking stage which is also successful.  I can see in Wireshark that the STUN request/response exchanges are also successful.

However, the candidate checking keeps going on and on, constantly sending/receiving the successful STUN requests/responses.

It is not obvious to me, and the example code does not show, how to actually stop the candidate checks when they have succeeded. I have called the API routine: nice_agent_attach_recv() and registered the callback but it does not seem to fire. And even if it did, the callback signature does not give me any clue as to how to process any of the data.

Question: what processing should be done in the ice_agent_attach_recv() callback?

Thanks,
-Andres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No processing in the callback should need to be done. You would need to call `nice_agent_get_local_candidates()` and then continue with credentials and so on. There is [a decent example here in the reference manual](https://nice.freedesktop.org/libnice/NiceAgent.html).

Comment: I am calling nice_agent_get_local_candidates() in my candidate-gathering-done callback.  Why should it be called in the ice_agent_attach_recv() callback?  Thanks for your response.

Comment: In the example it's not in the callback function, `nice_agent_get_local_candidates()` is on the line of code just after the `nice_agent_attach_recv()` call.